# Pandas - Graphing Unstacked DataFrame with Multiple Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame in Pandas that looks like this when unstacked

```
     Unique Sessions
Date      2016-06-21 2016-06-29
Name
ABCD             995      4,088
EFGH               8         25
OPEF               1          1
```

How do I get Pandas to plot a stacked bar chart from this DataFrame with the x-axis being the name and the y-axis being the numbers from the dates stacked?

```
# df is the stacked DataFrame
plot = df.unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, title="Test")
plot.set_xlabel("Name")
plot.set_ylabel("Num")
plt.savefig('testplot.png', dpi=1000)
```

This code will create a bar chart but only take in to consideration 2016-06-21 and will not stack 2016-06-29's numbers on top of the 21st's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[995, 4088], [8, 25], [1, 1]],
                  index=pd.Index(['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'OPEF'], name='Name'),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Unique Sessions'], ['2016-06-21', '2016-06-29']],
                                                     names=[None, 'Date']))

print df

     Unique Sessions           
Date      2016-06-21 2016-06-29
Name                           
ABCD             995       4088
EFGH               8         25
OPEF               1          1
```

#### What I did

```
plot = df['Unique Sessions'].plot.bar(stacked=True, title="Test")
plot.set_xlabel("Name")
plot.set_ylabel("Num")
```

[image]

Comment: Huh weird. It doesn't work for my table but it works when I manually put in yours.

Comment: Just a thought... is it the comma in 4,088?

Comment: Yeah they fixed it. Just added `thousands=','` to my read_csv line and it worked. Thanks!